# Affect an ICollection that is passed to a method as a parameter?

Tags: c#, linq, inheritance, collections

I have a class that has an `ICollection` property that is assigned by the constructor when the class is instantiated, but I want to bind this property to the original collection so that when it's updated/changed, the original list is as well. What is the best method of doing this?

Here's an example:

```
public class Organizations
{
    private ICollection<Organization> _orgs;

    public Organizations(ICollection<Organization> orgs)
    {
        _orgs = orgs;
    }

    public void TestAdd()
    {
        _orgs.Add(new Organization {Name = "Testing 123"});
    }
}


// in another class
public ActionResult TestApi()
{
    var tmp = new SyncTool.Core.Extensions.Zendesk.Organizations(ZendeskCache.Organizations.Data);
    var zd = ZendeskCache.Organizations.Data.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name.Contains("Testing 123"));

    //ZendeskCache.Org.... is a List<Organization>

    return Json(new {data = "tmp" }, AG);
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Is this not working?

Comment: Correct, the above does not work. The list does not contain the added item.

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong with this code. Does it throw an exception when you access `.First()`? How do you know it is not working?

Comment: I'm using `FirstOrDefault` in my code and it returns null. I will update the OP with a more comprehensive example.

Comment: Maybe `ZendeskCache.Organizations.Data` returns a new collection everytime? try to put it in a variable like this `var collection = ZendeskCache.Organizations.Data;`, and then use the `collection` variable both as the constructor argument of `Organizations` and when you test that it contains the "Testing `12" value.

Comment: Even assigning it to a variable, I run into the same issue.

Comment: Actually, I'm just unobservant. My apologies. In my production code, I was calling the constructor, but not the method within the class. Silly oversight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `List<Organization>` you are passing to the constructor is a reference object.  This code works the way you want it to (aside from syntax errors), have you tried it out?

To reproduce more simply:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var orgs = new List<string>();
        var orgClass = new Organizations(orgs);
        orgClass.TestAdd();
        Console.WriteLine(orgs.First());
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class Organizations
{
    private ICollection<string> _orgs;

    public Organizations(ICollection<string> orgs)
    {
        _orgs = orgs;
    }

    public void TestAdd()
    {
        _orgs.Add("Testing 123");
    }
}

//Output: "Testing 123"
```

Comment: I tried to simplify my code quite a bit to show an example, but it does add the item to the original list.

Comment: if you ever reassign `_orgs`, i.e. `_orgs = new List...`, then they will not be referencing the same object.  That's just speculation on what your problem might be, though.

Comment: I've updated the original code with a slightly better example, but it's pretty simple example.

Comment: Actually, I'm just unobservant. My apologies. In my production code, I was calling the constructor, but not the method within the class. Silly oversight.